# No microphones working on desktop

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, webcam, microphone

I have a laptop with Ubuntu on it and a desktop with Windows 7 on it. I always used my laptop for my microphone needs and stuff, until I moved my desktop into another room and kept the laptop in another room. No microphones will work with my desktop. I have tried EVERYTHING. I have tried USB microphones, the normal cabled microphones that go into the sound card (I tried using my soundcard and built in one). Windows picks them up SOMETIMES, says they work fine, but they don't record. I know the microphones work because they work on every other computer in my house. I've tried changing/updating/downgrading drivers, troubleshooting, restarting, tampering in the sound settings, nothing. The whole reason I got the USB microphones (plural) was because of this issue. However, any other kind of USB device works perfectly find, flash drives, keyboards, mice, ports, only microphones and webcams. What can I do? I am at a loss.

Comment: I know that you said you checked the sound settings, but it honestly seems to me that you need to make sure that the microphone is set to Default Device in the recording tab.

Comment: It is set as the default device. I am at a loss here.